# Padding of a wrapper/parent element doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, css

[image]
I'm using react and I have this piano component (from an external library) that is responsive.
On my app, I have 3 different "levels" that result with different ranges of that piano - meaning the horizontal length of the piano changes according to the level (harder means wider range).

I've wrapped the responsive piano with a *piano-div*.

[image]

**I want the height of the *piano-div* to be the same, so the level buttons won't move when switching between them. But I also want the piano to cover the page horizontally as much as possible (with a bit of a space on the sides).**
I approached this by adding padding:

```
.piano-div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8% 30%;
}

.responsive-piano{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-45%);
  transform: translateY(-45%);
}
```

The problem is, it's proportional for the "easy" level but the other 2 come off too small and they could really go longer horizontally. I tried playing with the padding/margin of the few elements involved but nothing worked (responsive-piano really messes up if you touch it).

I also tried doing DOM manipulation and change the padding according to the chosen level, based on this css:

```
.piano-div {
  position: relative;
}

.piano-div.easy {
  padding: 8% 30%;
}

.piano-div.hard {
  padding: 8% 5%;
}

.piano-div.crazy {
  padding: 8% 5%;
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working smoothly, when switching from easy to hard, the piano moves to the left:
[image]
If I move the whole page, it gives it a little "refresh" and then it looks fine:
[image]
But obviously I want it to work without moving the page :)

Any idea how to fix this? Or maybe an idea for a different approach?

**UPDATE:**

This is the relevant HTML code:

App.js:

```
<div className={"piano-div " + currGame.level}>
                  <ResponsivePiano className='responsive-piano' noteRange={LevelConf[currGame.level].noteRanges}
                  handleGuess={this.handleGuess} activeNotes={winningChord.activeNotes} audioContext={audioContext}/>
                </div>
```

ResponsivePiano.js:

```
function ResponsivePiano(props) {
  const { noteRange, handleGuess, activeNotes, audioContext } = props;
  return (
    <DimensionsProvider>
      {({ containerWidth, containerHeight }) => (
        <SoundfontProvider
          instrumentName="acoustic_grand_piano"
          audioContext={audioContext}
          hostname={soundfontHostname}
          handleGuess={handleGuess}
          render={({ isLoading, playNote, stopNote }) => (
            <Piano
              noteRange={noteRange}
              width={containerWidth}
              playNote={playNote}
              stopNote={stopNote}
              disabled={isLoading}
              activeNotes={activeNotes}
              {...props}
            />
          )}
        />
      )}
    </DimensionsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, it's helpful that you included lots of images, but for code (the HTML), it's better to provide text rather than an image, so that others can copy the text when referencing it instead of typing it out.
What happens if you try changing the `width` value in the `style` attribute of the `ReactPiano` div?

Comment: @vasia thanks for the reply! I didn't think the HTML code matters that much but I added it now to the question. Regarding the width, I tried to play with that too but it affects the height, so the levels buttons move... That's why I thought I should wrap it in a piano-div and make the changes there. Did you mean something else?

Comment: In the context of CSS, "responsive" does not mean what you think it means. Where are your media-queries? "Responsive" does not mean "changes in response to the difficulty of a game level".

Comment: @Dai it's actually from the demo of react-piano, they use the react-dimensions package which makes it responsive in a css-ish way, as I understand it. But in that demo they use the whole piano as a 100% width and the height changes accordingly (the piano range doesn't change). I'd like it to be in the same height (when switching between different piano ranges) and with a bit of a space on the sides... I used the responsive option so that if I stay with the same piano range and I shorten the page horizontally, the piano changes responsively too

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the flexbox instead.

```
.piano-div {
  display: flex,
  justify-content: center,
  align-items: center
}
```

That way your piano component will be always vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: That's great for centering but the height still changes, so the level buttons keep going up and down when switching between them

Comment: Seems like the buttons have to be in the parent component and the keyboard in the child. That way you won't have to re-render the buttons and you can set position absolute for them.